# python, break up into multiple mixins

Tags: python

client uses both `a` and `b` and MixinB uses `a`

```
class MixinA(object):

    def a(self):
        pass


class MixinB(object):

    def b(self):
        self.a()


class Client(MixinA, MixinB, object):

    def foo(self):
        self.a()
        self.b()
```

I'm uncomfortable MixinB calls `a` when it doesn't know about MixinA

---

Alternatively, I could do,

```
class MixinA(object):

    def a(self):
        pass


class MixinB(MixinA, object):

    def b(self):
        self.a()


class Client(MixinB, object):

    def foo(self):
        self.a()
        self.b()
```

Now, Client can't use MixinA without depending on MixinB,

There are ClientA, ClientB, and ClientA might want to MixinA only, but it needs to depend on MixinB (and has to know MixinB would bring in MinxA)

Comment: Wouldn't the mixins inherit from an interface? e.g. `MixinA : InterfaceA` and `MixinB : InterfaceA, InterfaceB`. In this case, you would let `MixinB` specify the behavior, and `MixinB` provides behavior of `MixinA`. Of course, this probably sounds a bit crazy in python...

Comment: What's wrong with option 2, anyways? Is it because you need to check that the `Client` is of "type" `MixinA`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I added a bit more on option 2

Comment: The question says, *ClientA might want to MixinA only, and it needs to depend on MixinB.*. But that doesn’t seem right...

Comment: @NicholasM I changed the wording a bit.. might be better

Comment: If you want `ClientX` to be able to specify the `MixinA` and `MixinB` separately, then `MixinB` should inherit from `InterfaceA`, but *not* from `MixinA`.

Comment: in my sugeestion create a parent class say C, which have a define, A, B interhit c, f calling to a is happending ie self.a(), then it will automatically overwrite the function and your code will remain good and concern regarding using a only go good with this

Comment: So I reread the first half of your question. What you have might be the simplest solution, though it probably creates linting errors. You can extract `self.a()` by passing it into the constructor of `MixinB` as a function of signature `def a(obj)`, or as a `BehaviorA` object (which is a more heavyweight Java-like style). You may not want to hear this, but it feels like at this point that you probably want composition rather than inheritance. Inheritance should only be used to "delegate methods of parent for me, and subtype". You only have one delegated method, and subtyping can be overcome.